# Using NodeJS, javascript in head can not use parameter from server

Tags: javascript, node.js, parameters

I'm making a page that receive string parameter from server when it is rendered. the parameter is shown correctly at body. but it shows "Uncaught ReferenceError: newestname is not defined" at jacascript function in  part. but in  part, the parameter is processed correctly and show it's data.

I think I'm missing quite basic thing to code. But I couldn't find while browsing internet for almost 4 hour. Please help me.

My js file in serverside give parameter like this.

```
res.render('index', { title: 'Express', newestname:newestname });
```

newestname is string value.

and at ejs file, it is processed at two part.

```
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(function() {
            $('#report').load(newestname);
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <%= newestname %>
    </div>
<body>
```

the parameter using bodypart works correctly. But parameter at head doesn't work. the error message is like below.

Uncaught ReferenceError: newestname is not defined

I've tried using $(document).ready(function() {} but it shows same error.

How can I make parameter at header works?

Answer (score 2):

You have to define the 'newestname' or you can directly pass '<%= newestname %>' to load function.
Try this.

```
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        let newestname= "<%= newestname %>";
        $(function() {
            $('#report').load(newestname);
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Thank you. I've tried <%= newestname %> but missed let and "".